# HowTo resize partitions in ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: partitioning, gnome, root, home-directory

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10, but i assigned only 4 GB to the /home partition. Now I figured that it's so small because Ubuntu saves files on home! Can i change it inside Ubuntu with some program or something else? I mean to get space from /root and move it to /home?(sorry if my English are bad! :) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) and install it via terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T)

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Via using this you can resize partitions as per your needs.

Here is a youtube video for [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1mJHSDade8k)

Answer (score 0):

4Gb can be more than enough. Options:

- symlink the directories in /home/$USER/ to a another partition.
- edit `.config/users-dirs.dirs` to point the directories to another partition.

Otherwise you can also resize your partition. Boot from a live dvd or from a gparted live dvd and use gparted to resize your partition: make 1 smaller, add it to /home/. You need a live session because you can not alter partitions that are in use.